# Como sumar una matriz n x n usando hilos (Thread)?

Tags: java, algoritmos, matrices

Quiero saber la manera de sumar una matriz cuadrada n x n usando hilos en java ya lo hize con una matriz fija de 2 x 2 pero no se me ocurre la menara de hacerlo con una matriz de  n x n .

```
//Clase Suma
 public class Suma extends Thread {

private int n1;
private int n2;
private int resultado;



public int getN1() {
    return n1;
}

public void setN1(int n1) {
    this.n1 = n1;
}

public int getN2() {
    return n2;
}

public void setN2(int n2) {
    this.n2 = n2;
}

public int getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}

public void setResultado(int resultado) {
    this.resultado = resultado;
}

public void run() {

    resultado = n1 + n2;

}

}

 //Clase Pincipal
 public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de matriz cuadrada:");
    int n = l.nextInt();

    int a[][] = new int[n][n];
    int b[][] = new int[n][n];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

            System.out.print("|" + a[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero para su  matriz cuadrada:");
    n = l.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {

            b[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print("|" + b[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    Suma s1 = new Suma();
    Suma s2 = new Suma();
    Suma s3 = new Suma();
    Suma s4 = new Suma();

    s1.setN1(a[0][0]);
    s1.setN2(b[0][0]);

    s2.setN1(a[0][1]);
    s2.setN2(b[0][1]);

    s3.setN1(a[1][0]);
    s3.setN2(b[1][0]);

    s4.setN1(a[1][1]);
    s4.setN2(b[1][1]);

    s1.start();
    s2.start();
    s3.start();
    s4.start();

    s1.join();
    s2.join();
    s3.join();
    s4.join();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Suma:");
    System.out.println("| " + s1.getResultado() + " , " + s2.getResultado() + " |");

    System.out.println("| " + s3.getResultado() + " , " +     s4.getResultado() + " |");

}

}
```

Comment: Fork join framework es tu aliado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La ejecución en varios hilos de ejecución puede mejorar el tiempo de ejecución. Pero hay que dividir el trabajo en paquetes de tamaño apropiado. Crear un `Thread` es una operación costosa y no tiene sentido hacerlo para sumar solo un `int`, sería más rápido hacer la suma directamente. Además, en general, no es útil tener más hilos que núcleos tiene nuestra CPU.

Por ese motivo vamos a dividir el trabajo por columnas, repartiendo las columnas de forma equilibrada entre un número fijo de hilos.

Primero una clase `SumaParalela` que es capaz de sumar múltiples columnas. Recibe como parámetros la matriz en que almacenar el resultado y las matrices a sumar. Así como un rango de columnas a sumar; de minCol (inclusive) a maxCol (no inclusive).

```
public class SumaParalela extends Thread {

    private final int[][] matrizRes;
    private final int[][] matrizA;
    private final int[][] matrizB;
    private final int minFil;
    private final int maxFil;

    public SumaParalela( int[][] matrizRes, int[][] matrizA, int[][] matrizB, 
            int minFil, int maxFil)
    {
        this.minFil = minFil;
        this.maxFil = maxFil;
        this.matrizRes = matrizRes;
        this.matrizA = matrizA;
        this.matrizB = matrizB;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for( int i=minFil; i<maxFil; ++i)
        {
            for ( int j=0; j<matrizRes[i].length; ++j )
                matrizRes[i][j] = matrizA[i][j] + matrizB[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Y ahora el código que pregunta al usuario cuántos hilos crear y reparte el trabajo de forma equitativa entre ellos.

Si el número de columnas es múltiplo del número de hilos (resto 0) la división es exacta. Si no es así los primeros (numColumnas%numHilos) procesan una columna más que el resto.

```
public class Principal {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de matriz cuadrada:");
    int n = l.nextInt();

    int a[][] = new int[n][n];
    int b[][] = new int[n][n];
    int res[][] = new int[n][n];

    System.out.println("Matriz A:");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

            System.out.print("|" + a[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    System.out.println("Matriz B:");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {

            b[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print("|" + b[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    // Crear hilos, repartir filas y ejecutarlos.
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de hilos:");
    int numHilos = l.nextInt();
    int resto = n % numHilos;
    SumaParalela[] hilos = new SumaParalela[numHilos];
    int fila = 0;
    int sigFila;
    for ( int h=0; h<numHilos; ++h ) {
        sigFila = fila + n/numHilos;
        if ( h<resto )
            ++sigFila;
        hilos[h] = new SumaParalela( res, a, b, fila, sigFila);
        hilos[h].start();
        fila = sigFila;
    }

    // Esperar que acaben los hilos;
    for ( int h=0; h<numHilos; ++h )
        hilos[h].join();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Suma:");
    for ( int i=0; i<res.length; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j=0; j<res[i].length; ++j )
            System.out.print(res[i][j] + "\t" );
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Jose Antonio Dura Olmos